# Contraction Mapping Question: rx(1 − x)

Tags: functional-analysis, contraction-mapping

I came across the following question:

- Let (R, | · |) be a metric space. Let r ≥ 0 and define the mapping L : R → R where L(x) = rx(1 − x).
- When is this a contraction mapping?

Let x,y in R. Thus, we have:

- |L(x) - L(y)| = |rx(1-x) - ry(1-y)| = |r|.|x(1-x) - y(1-y)| = r.|x - x² - y + y²| ≤ r(|x-y| + |y² - x²|) = r|x-y| + r|y² - x²|

Since |y² - x²| ≥ 0, I cannot conclude when this is a contraction mapping.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably know that $x^2 - y^2 = (x - y) (x+y)$. If you are free to choose the domain of $L$, you can formulate the condition.

Comment: Is $R$ something else aside a metric space, like a ring, vector space, etc ...? Otherwise, what does $rx(1-x)$ mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If your metric space is the real line with the usual metric then  $L$ is contracytion only when $r=0$.

Comment: @Dmitry thank you for the tip. I think I  got it right!.